# how to embed a website on xblock?

Tags: python, json, openedx

I'm new and working on a project to display a website content on xblock. I want to display the content of this website:  [decheck.it/codecheck/files?repo=bj4cc&problem=ch02/c02_exp_2_102](http://codecheck.it/codecheck/files?repo=bj4cc&problem=ch02/c02_exp_2_102)

Most the link of the website has `"codecheck.it/codecheck/files?repo="` similar in general. I wonder if anyone know what should i do in order to display the content of the website?
I saw an example on embed vimeo.com but i'm not sure if it's the same for website:

```
 if hostname == 'vimeo.com':
            oembed_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json'
```

the link is from this tutorial [here](http://opencraft.com/doc/edx/xblock/tutorial.html)

Thanks

Comment: give us more info, like how these url's are generated, what is the purpose of xblock, which doc have you been referring ? embedding this url in xblock can be done using `iframe`

Comment: Hi, the purpose of xblock is display the codecheck website content and i want to use beautifulsoup to display the content later since the website break into different part where students have to enter the answer so I don't think iframe would work. btw, I updated the question

Comment: why are you using bsp to embed the content if you can use `iframe` directly ?

Comment: Hi because i want to break down the content of the website into different section

Comment: like ? just give an example with http://codecheck.it/codecheck/files?repo=bj4cc&problem=ch02/c02_exp_2_102

Comment: for example, if I just want to display in xblock:
r = urllib2.urlopen(url= "http://codecheck.it/codecheck/files?repo=bj4cc&problem=ch02/c02_exp_2_102") and b = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml"); then print out just the question text for print b.pre.text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95915/discussion-between-frank-and-hong-le).

Comment: @frank hey frank sorry i just saw your message! So how did you manage to show it ? Even the submitting form redirect to codecheck site should be fine. Thanks